# Get which vertex of a feature is modified

Tags: events, openlayers

I was trying to get which vertex of a Feature has been modified. It seems that `featuremodified` event does not supply this information.

this is important because I will have to post the modification to the server. I dont want to post the whole feature object because of one single vertex change.

I am using OpenLayers `v2.13.1`

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook into the vertexmodified callback of OpenLayers.Layer.Vector. This is triggered by the dragVertex function of OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature, see line 479 here http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Control/ModifyFeature.js

The vertexmodified function receives a vertex, a feature and a pixel, so you would write something like this, assuming an OpenLayers.Layer.Vector called vector:

```
vector.events.register('vertexmodified', this, function(vertex, feature, pixel){
    //do something with the vertex
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, the problem is, it fires whenever the vertex is moved a little. I need a `aftervertexmodified` event which I cannot find. I suppose I need a little tweak with `vertexmodified` and `featuremodified`.

Comment: Yes, I can't see any other way than combining vertexmodified and featuremodified.